# Method that accepts Function or Float for any parameter

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am basically trying to return a Function, used for a Stream, where any parameter can be either a Float or a Function. I was looking to make the input of dynamic values simpler for creative coding applications and feel I'm in over my head with streams and generics.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? Overloading the method would create a lot of duplicate code since I want any parameter to be either type. Also I looked at trying to create an interface, but couldn't do it without creating new class instances just to input a float as a parameter.

```
class A{
  Function<PVector, Float> range( Object scale, Object min, Object max ){
    FObj<PVector> fScale = getFO( scale );
    FObj<PVector> fMin = getFO( min );
    FObj<PVector> fMax = getFO( max );
    return pv -> map(noise(pv.x * fScale.getValue( pv ), pv.y * fScale.getValue( pv ) ), 0, 1, fMin.getValue( pv ), fMax.getValue( pv ) );
  }
  
  <T> FObj<T> getFO ( Object input ) {
    if( input instanceof Float ) return new FObj<T>( (Float) input );
    else if( input instanceof Function ) return new FObj<T>( (Function<T,Float>)input );
    else throw new java.lang.RuntimeException("error");
  }
  
}


class FObj<T>{
  Function<T, Float> fn;
  float val;
  
  FObj( Function<T, Float> fn ){
    this.fn = fn;
  }
  
  FObj( float val ){
    this.val = val;
  }
  
  float getValue( T input ){
    return fn != null ? fn.apply( input ) : val;
  }
}
```

Two use cases for range method at s and s2:

```
A a;
List<PVector> pvs = new ArrayList<>();
pvs.add( new PVector( 0, 0 ) );
        
Stream s =  pvs.stream().map( a.range( 0.02f, 0f, 255f )::apply );
Stream s2 = pvs.stream().map( a.range( a.range( 0.02f, 0.1f, 0.002f ), 0f, 255f )::apply );
```

Comment: You could just accept an identity function for float that accepts and returns the same value.

Comment: In am curious as to why you say - " but couldn't do it without creating new class instances just to input a float as a parameter."

Comment: If possible I would like to avoid something like range( new FloatObject(0.5), new FloatObject(0),  new FloatObject(1) ); for a simple use case

Comment: This question does not belong in Stack Overflow. For starters, it is opinion-based. Secondly, it seems more appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). I suggest you post your question there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It belongs in Code Review. Also, it is opinion-based.

Comment: Trying to have a single class represent both of these very different things is likely to be complicated and ugly.

Comment: I don't see the class PVector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    List<PVector> pvs = List.of(new PVector(0, 0));

    Stream<Double> s = pvs.stream().map(new RangeBuilder().scale(.02)
                                                          .min(0)
                                                          .max(255)
                                                          .build());
    Stream<Double> s2 = pvs.stream().map(new RangeBuilder().scale(new RangeBuilder().scale(.02)
                                                                                    .min(.1)
                                                                                    .max(.002)
                                                                                    .build())
                                                           .min(0)
                                                           .max(255)
                                                           .build());

}

public static final class RangeBuilder {

    private Function<PVector, Double> scale;
    private Function<PVector, Double> min;
    private Function<PVector, Double> max;

    public RangeBuilder scale(Function<PVector, Double> scale) {
        this.scale = scale;
        return this;
    }

    public RangeBuilder scale(double scale) {
        return scale(in -> scale);
    }

    public RangeBuilder min(Function<PVector, Double> min) {
        this.min = min;
        return this;
    }

    public RangeBuilder min(double min) {
        return min(in -> min);
    }

    public RangeBuilder max(Function<PVector, Double> max) {
        this.max = max;
        return this;
    }

    public RangeBuilder max(double scale) {
        return scale(in -> scale);
    }

    public Function<PVector, Double> build() {
        return pv -> map(noise(pv.x * scale.apply(pv), pv.y * scale.apply(pv)), 0, 1, min.apply(pv), max.apply(pv));
    }

}
```

***P.S.** I user `double` instead of `float`, because this is default type for floating point numbers*.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the class `FObj<T>` like this:

```
class FObj<T> {
    Function<T, Float> fn;

    FObj(Function<T, Float> fn) {
        this.fn = fn;
    }

    FObj(float val) {
        this.fn = t -> val;
    }

    float getValue(T input) {
        return fn.apply(input);
    }
}
```

But this is almost equivalent to `Function<T, Float>`, so you don't need it.

```
class A {
    Function<PVector, Float> range(
            Function<PVector, Float> fScale,
            Function<PVector, Float> fMin,
            Function<PVector, Float> fMax) {
        return pv -> map(noise(pv.x * fScale.apply(pv), pv.y * fScale.apply(pv)),
            0, 1, fMin.apply(pv), fMax.apply(pv));
    }
}
```

and

```
A a = new A();
List<PVector> pvs = new ArrayList<>();
pvs.add( new PVector( 0, 0 ) );
        
Stream<Float> s =  pvs.stream().map(
    a.range( p -> 0.02f, p -> 0f, p -> 255f )::apply );
Stream<Float> s2 = pvs.stream().map(
    a.range(a.range( p -> 0.02f, p -> 0.1f, p -> 0.002f ),
        p -> 0f, p -> 255f )::apply );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Oleg's suggestion of the builder pattern is more in line for my needs but this approach could work as well